# Linking K2 item to another Category

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

I have an issue though, and I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have a category called "Stock Colors" as a menu item, and it's on category.

I also have another K2 item posted on the home page, based in another category also called "Stock Colors," and this category is supposed to be used to show the available colors for this company.

I would like to be able to add a link on the Custom Module called "Stock Colors" to the Category for "Stock Colors"

Any help would be beyond appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Saying Custom Module, you mean the core custom html module?

Comment: Not, Just a front end K2 Module. On the homepage of the site.

Comment: To be honest, I was not able to fully understand what you want to do. I asked if it is a custom html module, because that would be easy to add your own content in there. If this is another module, you might need to customize it, if it doesn't provide settings to do what you want. Maybe posting and explaining better your question in http://joomla.stackexchange.com/, can give you an answer.